# Symfony "cannot fetch TableMap" error when using propel:build-all

Tags: symfony1, propel

```
Cannot fetch TableMap for undefined table: order_product.  Make sure you have the static MapBuilder registration code after your peer stub class definition.
```

Even if I erase the entire schema, clear the cache, and delete everything but "vendor" in the lib folder, I still get the error. I also get the error when doing propel:build-filters or propel:build-forms.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had defined a class with the same name as one of the models. Whoops.